# PHP, access data in JSON by using class

Tags: php, json, class, oop

I need to use class to access data from a JSON database. My code has some errors but I don't know where they are. Anyone can show what do I need to change to make it work? Thanks.

```
<?php

class Character {

        private $name;

public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;

        }
public function getName($name){
        return $this->name;
        }


}

$data = file_get_contents("databas.json");
            $data = json_decode($data, true);

            foreach($data['results'] as $e) {
            $character = new Character($e['name']);
            $characters[] = $character;
            }

            foreach($characters as $character) {
            echo "Name: " . $character->getName();
            } 


 ?>
```

Comment: `My code has some errors but` show the error

Comment: Please also share any errors or hints as to what goes wrong, provide an expected output and what you get. In the current format your question is too generic, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to initialize the `$characters[]`array outside of the loop

Comment: without sharing errors, its difficult to answer.. some hint , use `print_r($data)`; before `$data = json_decode($data, true);` and share the result

Comment: or MAYBE u have typo in your file name  `databas.json`

Answer (score -1):

You method has an extra arg

```
public function getName($name){
    return $this->name;
}
```

Which will issue an error when you call it like this

```
$character->getName()
```

Without the required argument: in this case just remove that from the method definition.  I suppose you copied it and renamed it then forgot to remove the argument, etc...  Not to worry I've done that like a billion times...

```
public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}
```

Your code in a [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68b6405ddc64f4c038d4d9c4e359347f991bb1c3)

Output:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for Character::getName(), called in [...][...] on line 26 and defined in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
Name: foo
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still cant get it working.